# Code for Google Analytic product hit in c#

Tags: c#, google-analytics

I'm new in google analytic. I go through some regarding this. I found that there is no direct method to hit a windows application in google analytic. But i found some solutions in stackoverflow. I tried that, but didn't work for me. Below is the code that I'm using.

`private void analyticsmethod4(string trackingId, string pagename)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();`

```
        long timestampFirstRun, timestampLastRun, timestampCurrentRun, numberOfRuns;

        // Get the first run time
        timestampFirstRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
        timestampLastRun = DateTime.Now.Ticks - 5;
        timestampCurrentRun = 45;
        numberOfRuns = 2;

        // Some values we need
        string domainHash = "123456789"; // This can be calcualted for your domain online
        int uniqueVisitorId = rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999); // Random
        string source = "Shop";
        string medium = "medium123";
        string sessionNumber = "1";
        string campaignNumber = "1";
        string culture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        string screenRes = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width + "x" + Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;

        string statsRequest = "http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif" +
            "?utmwv=4.6.5" +
            "&utmn=" + rnd.Next(100000000, 999999999) +
            //  "&utmhn=hostname.mydomain.com" +
            "&utmcs=-" +
            "&utmsr=" + screenRes +
            "&utmsc=-" +
            "&utmul=" + culture +
            "&utmje=-" +
            "&utmfl=-" +
            "&utmdt=" + pagename + // Here i passed my profile name "MyWindowsApp"
            "&utmhid=1943799692" +
            "&utmr=0" +
            "&utmp=" + pagename +
            "&utmac=" + trackingId + //Tracking id : ie "UA-XXXXXXXX-X"
            "&utmcc=" +
                "__utma%3D" + domainHash + "." + uniqueVisitorId + "." + timestampFirstRun + "." + timestampLastRun + "." + timestampCurrentRun + "." + numberOfRuns +
                "%3B%2B__utmz%3D" + domainHash + "." + timestampCurrentRun + "." + sessionNumber + "." + campaignNumber + ".utmcsr%3D" + source + "%7Cutmccn%3D(" + medium + ")%7Cutmcmd%3D" + medium + "%7Cutmcct%3D%2Fd31AaOM%3B";

        try
        {
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                //byte[] bt = client.DownloadData(statsRequest);
                Stream data = client.OpenRead(statsRequest);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                MessageBox.Show(s);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

This example is also got from this site itself. I don't know where was the problem. Please direct me, how can i make it. This is the output i'm getting "GIF89a".

Thanks
Bobbin Paulose

Comment: Check my answer in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36595299/is-it-possible-to-post-windows-form-hit-info-to-google-analyticstrack-id-using

Answer (score 0):

So it's working. The Google Analytics call loads a tiny GIF image, and the querystring parameters provided in the request trigger all the Google Analytics goodness. If you're getting a response back, you have registered your event successfully with Google.

Comment: But if i check my google analytic, I cant see any hits. Is there anything more I need to set in my google analytic account, to see the hits.

Comment: Give it time - they don't show up in the front end immediately.

Comment: I tried this code from last 2 days. But there is nothing show in my google analytic account